# jQuery Regex Check on field works but alert message doesn't change

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this function to validate postcodes (UK):

```
/* validate Post Code */
$.fn.validatePostCode = function(postcode)
{
    regex = /^[A-Za-z]{1,2}\d{1,2}\s*\d{1}[A-Za-z]{2}$/i;

    if (!regex.test(postcode)) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

as you can see it's just a simple regex checking for amount of character types at certain points.

To trigger it (or at least in the part I'm using it for) I use:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#nextBtn').on('click', function()
    {
        var postcode = $('#postcode').val();
        console.log(postcode);

        if (!$.fn.validatePostCode(postcode)) {
            alert('hi');
        } else {
            alert('not valid');
        }
    });
});
```

doing the console.log is so I can see the value of the postcode each check, and I can see it updates. However, upon changing the input so I know it should be wrong still alert('hi') instead of Not Valid. I've even added a console.log in my validate function and that shows when the postcode is invalid, so why doesn't the alert message change each click?

I used this to validate my regex: http://www.regextester.com/ and it said my pattern was ok when I typed various postcodes in, so I'm a little lost at the moment, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution rather quickly - it's because my function doesn't return a value until it fails. Needed to add a `return true;` outside of the if statement.

Hope this helps anyone who has a similar problem :)

Comment: This also could do the work, since `.test` return a boolean value: `$.fn.validatePostCode = function(postcode)
{
   return  /^[A-Za-z]{1,2}\d{1,2}\s*\d{1}[A-Za-z]{2}$/i.test(postcode))        
};`